# My files transfer sometimes at .5MBs sometimes at 100 MBs, Why?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

This is not related to [disk caching](https://superuser.com/questions/315134/why-does-my-flash-drive-speed-slow-down-when-copying/315145). I have to transfer terabytes of data often between Sata and usb and internal nvme drives. Sometimes the transfers are over 100MBps, and sometimes they are kbps. How could I trouble shoot or fix this? I am Usb attached serial protocol compliant because sometimes the transfers complete at over 100MBs. I thought maybe a usb2.0 attached device might force lower speeds but I detached every other usb device. All my ports are 3.0.

---

This is also not related to small files slowing down the transfer as the files are every other file small and large and no runs of small/large files that would run for hours.

---

I found the answer:
My hard drive is a [Seagate Expansion 8TB Desktop External Hard Drive USB 3.0 (STEB8000100](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HAPGEIE)) which uses **SMR: Shingled Magnetic Recording**

According to backblaze there are two main types of [recording technologies](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/hard-drive-buying-guide/?utm_source=Email&utm_medium=Newsletter-B1&utm_content=hd-buying-tips-b&utm_campaign=Newsletter-20181211):

> **PMR: Perpendicular Magnetic Recording** This is the technology inside of
> most hard drives. With PMR data is written to and read from circular
> tracks on a spinning platter.
>
> **SMR: Shingled Magnetic Recording** This
> type of drive overlaps recording tracks to store data at a lower cost
> than PMR technology. The downside occurs when data is deleted and that
> space is reused. If existing data overlaps the space you want to
> reuse, this can mean delays in writing the new data. These drives are
> great for archive storage (write once, read many) use cases, but if
> your files turn over with some regularity, stick with PMR drives.

Comment: Many small files vs. few large files?

Comment: @grono They are all mixed with large and small files all interspersed in all copies. I found that disk compression causes this which on one of my drives is enabled, but that wouldn't explain why sometimes it's fast for hours and sometimes not fast for hours

Comment: From your description, the quoted duplicate does not appear to answer your question. I suggest you run a monitor (such as SysInternals' [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) during a copy and check for CPU and I/O activity when the copy slows. Also check the SMART data on the source and target disc: it could be that one of the discs is failing, with multiple retries in the affected areas.

Comment: @afh that's exactly what I spent the day doing. Do you have any specific events I should look for? Crystal diskinfo reports all good health and proctor has been showing file notexists and invalid parameter.

Comment: Process Explorer can be configured to show different graphs: look for high values, then hover over the graph to show the the process that is contributing most to the instantaneous value.